# Is changing of branch in git of django project need new database in mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, git

Basically, I want to do some changes in my Django project but I want my previous content to keep unchanged. As my Django is connected with MySQL database in **WAMP** server and my project's database name Django_movies. With the help of git I did this with changing branch from master to another.

My question is: May I have to create a new database in MySQL to work on other branches or git will handle this for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git doesn't know about your database, and it certainly won't create a new one for you. (It also doesn't know about Python or Django or what your code does. It just records commits you make.)

I'm a bit confused about why you want another database, though. You can use the same database across all of your branches and unless you're working on changes that require database migrations there's no problem.

Even if you *are* working on database changes you can run your migrations forwards and backwards to modify your database schema as you switch branches. And in many cases you [don't even have to do that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#version-control), though personally I prefer to keep a linear migration history.